# How to scroll UP to an element and click in selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a scenario where system needs to scroll UP to the webelement in the left panel of the page and click to perform other operations.I have tried the below ways but none of them are working.Please suggest :

1.

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    Thread.sleep(500);
```

2.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element"));
 Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(ele);
        actions.perform();
```

Comment: What the error you getting?

Comment: @frianH : am getting this error  " org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[text()='some text']"} "

Comment: Can you try to modify your locator to .//*[contains(text(),'some text')]

Comment: @Rahul Are you sure with your locator ? it seem like element not found in the pages. Please share html.

Comment: @frianH : It is working fine until the element is visible i.e, when other text is being added below that element , webdriver is unable to scroll up to that desired element and perform actions.sorry, html cannot be shared as it is private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Up* or *Down* to `scrollIntoView()` an element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use the following solution:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("element"))));
```