# How to make selenium to scroll to view ability of element

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, js-scrollintoview

Hey All I have a question regarding selenium
I have a very long form, and I want to scroll a little bit down for entering data.
I do not want it to scroll all the way just until the element is displayed.

I used this code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

It not worked since selenium scroll to match down, is their a way it will scroll to this element so I Can enter data to it, for example to scroll until element is in the moddle of screen.
I do not know what is the purpose of scroll into view if it is scrolling not to view 
regards

Comment: Shouldn't Selenium scroll to the field, if it is outside of the viewport, when you are trying to send keys to it?

Answer (score 2):

If your usecase is to *...scroll a little bit down for entering data...* you have multiple ways to achieve that:

- You can induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` which will **automatically scroll** the desired element within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) as follows:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(locator))).sendKeys("Bastian");
  ```
- You can use `Actions` class method `moveToElement()` inconjunction with `sendKeys()` as well which will also **automatically scroll** the desired element within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) as follows:

  ```
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(locator)).sendKeys("Bastian").build().perform();
  ```
- You can still use `scrollIntoView()` method to scroll the element first and then induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` as follows:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.findElement(locator));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(locator))).sendKeys("Bastian");
  ```
- You can also use [`scrollBy()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681172/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-scroll-options/54689339#54689339) method to scroll down certain amount of `xy-coord` (adjusted) as follows and then locate the element:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,400)");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(locator))).sendKeys("Bastian");
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to scroll UP to an element and click in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886380/how-to-scroll-up-to-an-element-and-click-in-selenium/57886960#57886960)
- [Scrolling to top of the page in Python using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576958/scrolling-to-top-of-the-page-in-python-using-selenium/45581830#45581830)
- [Selenium python Error: element could not be scrolled into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56085152/selenium-python-error-element-could-not-be-scrolled-into-view/56361554#56361554)

Comment: The issue is not to wait, It can be wait for hours since the element I want to click is not display. and the scroll takes me to much down and still not see the element. I need selenium to stop scroll at the point the actually can do something press element click on it and so

Comment: @Bastian Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this. It works for me.

```
 public void scrollElementToCenter(WebElement element) {

        try {
            if (EnvironmentConstants.RUNNING_ON_CHROME) {
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                        .executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: \"auto\", block: \"center\", inline: \"nearest\"});", element);
            } else {
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", element);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException exception) {
            //LOGGER.error("UnsupportedOperationException occurred : " + exception.getMessage(), exception);
        }
    }
```

for **Chrome** browser you can use it

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                        .executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: \"auto\", block: \"center\", inline: \"nearest\"});", element);
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific, I Need the function only to chrome.  another question if I want that the method will get  By locator as an input what to change?

Comment: @Bastian, I have mentioned specially for chrome, Please try that piece of code. You need to pass only webelement  in this  :   ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                        .executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: \"auto\", block: \"center\", inline: \"nearest\"});", webElement);

Answer (score 0):

This is what I created and seems to be working for me.

```
for i in range(5000):
    browse = "window.scrollTo(0," + str(i) + ")"
    browser.execute_script(browse)
    i = i + 400
```

It pretty much scrolls slowly so every element on the page is loaded.