# windows scroll is not working in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have to click at an element which is intercepted by other element, so what i'm doing is that, I'm trying to scroll down the Vertical scroll bar and try to click my target element, so to scroll this i'm using the below code

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, -800)", "");
```

But the above code is not scrolling down the scroll bar

Note: i also tried to movetoelement. That is also not working, please help me with your solutions

```
action.moveToElement(seatLayout.seat_A16);
Thread.sleep(2000);
seatLayout.seat_A16.click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scroll down:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 800)", "");
```

To scroll up:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, -800)", "");
```

To scroll the element within the [viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130869/7429447):

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [What is the difference between the different scroll options?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54689339/7429447)
- [How to scroll UP to an element and click in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57886960/7429447)
- [scrollIntoView() not working for horizontal scroll (Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58537189/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this method

```
public static void scrollToTheBottom() {
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight * 0.9)");
    }
```

here 0-1 is the height of the page. I have selected 0.9 for my project